# Json-Binding API fromJson method returning List<HashMap>

Tags: java, generics, jsonb-api

I am trying to deserialize a json from a file using [JSON-B](https://javaee.github.io/jsonb-spec/users-guide.html) API

Here is the code

```
public List<User> getUsers(String file) {
    InputStream is = getResourceAsStream(file);
    return JsonbBuilder.create().fromJson(is, new ArrayList<User>(){}.getClass().getGenericSuperclass());
}
```

It works as expected.

I tried to generalize this method instead of hardcoding `User`, but it doesn't seem to work

```
public static <T> List<T> getFromSource(String file, Class<T> t) {
 InputStream is = getResourceAsStream(file);
 return getJsonb().fromJson(is, t.getGenericSuperclass());
}
```

Trying to call the above method

```
List<User> users = getFromSource("users.json", User.class);
User user = user.get(0);
```

But, it threw `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap incompatible with User`
So, looks like it is a `List<HashMap>` despite `List<User>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your working method the type is:

```java
new ArrayList<User>(){}.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()
```

But what you are passing into your `getFromSource()` method is effectively:

```java
User.class.getGenericSuperclass()
```

To fix this, you need to update the parameter passed in like this:

```
List<User> users = getFromSource("users.json", new ArrayList<User>(){}.getClass());
```

Comment: Could you add why it is returning HashMap type?

Comment: Probably because the code was effectively doing `getJsonb().fromJson(is, Object.class)` and the default container object for deserializaing a field with multiple values is to put it into a HashMap